# how to set up azure mobile service to deliver periodic updates to a windows 8 (store) App?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-runtime, azure-mobile-services

I want to add periodic tile updates to my windows store App, everything works ok if I provide a xml to the tileUpdateManager like for example this address http://wowzappelsalvador.azurewebsites.net/tiletest.xml. 
 The app works with an azure mobile service and the idea is to have the App tile updated using the same service so I created a read script on azure like this:

```
function read(query, user, request) {

mssql.query("select imagenTile, nombreTip from verdetips.tipDiaLiveTileView", {
    success: function(results) {

        var xmlEscape = function (text) {
        return text.replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
           .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
           .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
           .replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
        }

         var payload = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>" +
         "<tile><visual><binding template='TileWideImageAndText01'>" +
          "<image id='1' src='" + xmlEscape(results[0].imagenTile) + "' alt='Verde Tips'/>" +
          "<text id='1'>" + xmlEscape(results[0].nombreTip) + "</text>" +
          "</binding>" +
          "<binding template='TileSquareText04'>" +
          "<text id='1'>" + xmlEscape(results[0].nombreTip) + "</text>" +
          "</binding></visual></tile>";

         console.log(payload);
         request.respond(statusCodes.OK, payload);
    }
 });
}
```

when I call the table associated with this script I get the same text as on the .xml file but on a .json file and the tile update doesn't work, what am I missing?

Note: I've seen some sites explaining how to use push.wns.send on azure mobile services to send push or toast notifications but my case is a polled notification, client code as follows:

```
var notifications = Windows.UI.Notifications;
    var polledUri = new Windows.Foundation.Uri("http://verdetips.azure-mobile.net/tables/tipDiaLiveTile");
    //var polledUri = new Windows.Foundation.Uri("http://wowzappelsalvador.azurewebsites.net/tiletest.xml");
    var recurrence = notifications.PeriodicUpdateRecurrence.daily;
    var tileUpdater = notifications.TileUpdateManager.createTileUpdaterForApplication();
    tileUpdater.startPeriodicUpdate(polledUri, recurrence);
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment Azure Mobile Services don't have the capability of returning anything other than JSON. This is a recurrent request, so this feature is in the roadmap and should be implemented in the near future.

Comment: It looks to me like they're trying to build a tile update, which coud be done through the Push Notification Object in Mobile Services, correct?

Comment: i see, good to know its in the roadmap, @PatrickGodwin yes, a tile update is exactly what the App needs, usually you would set up an url containing the xml for the tile and have the app check on it every xx time...but given that the app uses a mobile service i wanted to use that... do you think sending a push notification every day to every app installed would do the trick if i want to do it with the existing mobile service?